# Get blur filter value from keyframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyframe

Hei guys, is there a way of getting blur filter value in javascript?

Got something like this:

```
@keyframes move {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
        filter: blur(5px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
        filter: blur(0px);
    }
}
```

And i'd like to get the blur filter pxs value.

What i have tried:

```
blurValue0 = elementsArray[0].style["webkitFilter"];
blurValue1 = elementsArray[0].style.filter;
```

Both are blank in the console...

Also, is there a way to use blur filter on different axis? Like xBlur or yBlur? (for images, i know for text is textshadow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this to get the digit value, or could carry out various matches to get the type of filter:

```
document.getElementById('testBlur').style['-webkit-filter'].match(/\d+/)
```

Sorry, but don't know about filtering along an axis...

********************EDIT*********************

OK, so looking like you can do something with getComputedStyle as below. Let me know how you get on with this:

```
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('testBlur'), "");

 for (var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
     if (styles[i].match('-webkit-filter')) {
         console.log(styles['-webkit-filter']);
         break;
     }
 }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3kwjxog8/

Comment: It's ok, i've been investigating abit about filters on different axis... its difficult :( And about the problem i have now, i'm about to test your solution, i will let you know if its working or not. Thanks

Comment: looking as though my solution has to be inline styles being declared. Will keep working on it.

Comment: I'm about to check it, lemme see

Comment: The console returns none :(

Comment: added fiddle to answer

Comment: Oh, then why it return none to my example... anyway, seems to work so it deserve +1 and accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find the filter only if you set it dynamically such as

```
elementsArray[0].style["-webkit-filter"] = "blur(1px)";
```

Then, it will dynamically blur your object and `elementsArray[0].style["-webkit-filter"]` will return `blur(1px)`.

I'm actually not sure why setting it through css results in the value being empty in the console though. Very interested in the answer.

Also, you can't individually set `blur` for x and y axis as of this point.

Comment: +1 for the explanation you gaved to me... Thats not good for me as i have goal not to add css from js :(

Comment: Also, i have no clue neither why the console is blank if it is set from css and i try to get its value from js ...

Comment: I see. An alternative you can do is checking your element for the current blur class, such as what you have now. If the element has class `0%`, you know there is 0 blur while if it has class `100%`, you know it has 5px blur.

Comment: Well, i dont need to get the 0 value too, just the initial value (5px). Lemme explain you what i wanna do with it: I'd like to get the value for further modifications -> blur filter value * aspectRatio of each element = new blur filter for each element -> insert the new blur filter in the css rules. I was thinking i can get it with getComputedStyle?

Comment: I'm not sure, you can give it a shot. The only difference I know of between `getComputedStyle` and `.style` is that `getComputedStyle` is `readonly`.

Comment: Hmmm, i have stored the first and the last keyframe value (0% and 100%). I'm about to check the first one for blur filter value... I just thought i can get the filter value easier :(

Comment: Also null :( firstKeyframe = cssRuleList[0].style.getPropertyValue("transform"); it works ... but if i change the property to filter... console returns null :|

Comment: Maybe because blur is a relatively new feature, browsers don't fully support it yet :(

Comment: Well... i'm about to add the blur from js ... thats it :( That way i wont need to get its value... ill create the css block with a variable that holds the blur value so i can listen to it ...